# Jira Gadget: Get all Issues of specific type

Tags: java, jquery, jira, jira-plugin

I'd like to create a new chart gadget for jira using jfreechart. To collect all the information I need for the chart, I need all issues of a certain issue type.
How do I look them up in my java class?
More specific, if I want to use a jquery I need the currently logged in user. How do I get the appropriate user object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
First get those two objects via constructor injection:

```
final SearchService searchService
final JiraAuthenticationContext authenticationContext
```

Then execute your query like that:

```
            final SearchResults results = searchService.search(authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), query,
                PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter());
        return results.getIssues();
```